# Reading Default Appearance of an EnterpriseArchitect Element by script

Tags: automation, scripting, enterprise-architect, appearance

the EA API provides the `Element.setAppearance()` method for setting the default appearance of an element in diagrams; the `Style` attribute, for the corresponding diagramObjects, is readable&writable. But what about **get**ting the default appearance of an element, since there is no `getAppearance()` method on Element?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to get used to the "API" of EA. The back door is the main entrance :-/

```
Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT Backcolor, Bordercolor, BorderStyle, BorderStyle FROM t_object WHERE ea_guid = '{2C80CA03-DF98-433e-8C32-1EABB4957133}'")
```

(You need to use the element's GUID instead of the sample)

This will return the numeric values of the columns in an XML string (see EA's help about `SQLQuery` or just look at the string returned):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EADATA version="1.0" exporter="Enterprise Architect">
<Dataset_0><Data><Row><Backcolor>1993170</Backcolor><Bordercolor>-1</Bordercolor><Expr1002>0</Expr1002><BorderStyle>0</BorderStyle></Row></Data></Dataset_0></EADATA>
```

Comment: Good response, but bad method :-) Thanks !

Comment: I'm not responsible for EA's API and UI. If I were I probably got me hanging the next tree :-/

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I do not reproach anything to you : Your response does the job, I'll probably use it, but the way let by EA is dirty :-)